# PHP-FastCGI start command not found

Tags: server, php

I have set up Nginx on my server, and now want to allow it for php files too, i followed http://library.linode.com/web-servers/nginx/php-fastcgi/ubuntu-10.04-lucid step by step.

But for `/etc/init.d/php-fastcgi` start command it shows file not found. Please help me out.

Comment: You want to look into `php-fpm` rather than the older `php-fastcgi` methods. It's quite a bit more robust. It's still based on fastcgi, but it's a process manager that can limit and look after itself better than `php-fastcgi`

Answer (score 1):

You must have forgotten [the step where you download the init script](http://library.linode.com/web-servers/nginx/php-fastcgi/ubuntu-10.04-lucid#configure_fastcgi):

```
wget https://library.linode.com/web-servers/nginx/php-fastcgi/reference/php-fastcgi-init-deb.sh
mv php-fastcgi-init-deb.sh /etc/init.d/php-fastcgi
chmod +x /etc/init.d/php-fastcgi
```

Comment: script is not exists.